# WSO2 Script mediator showing integer as float

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to read value of a property mediator of type INTEGER ,inside a Script mediator and was trying to do some arithmetic operations.Below is the corresponding code snippet.

```
<property expression="$trp:RETRY_COUNT" name="RETRY_COUNT"
        scope="default" type="INTEGER"
        xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" />

    <script language="js"><![CDATA[
          var retry_count_from_header = mc.getProperty('RETRY_COUNT');
          var counter = 1 ;
          if(retry_count_from_header >= 0){ 
                retryCountIncremented =  (Number(retry_count_from_header) + counter);
           }
     ]]></script>
```

The value of *'counter'* variable is evaluated as 1.0 instead of 1.
Hence the value of '*retryCountIncremented* ' is always a floating number.

Also tired to use Math.trunc() functions but Math function but getting the error 'TypeError: Cannot find function trunc in object [object Math]'

How to remove the decimal number .I am expecting the counter to an integer with out decimal point.
Also why the variable is always evaluated as float ?

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue and it's related to the word `expression` if you use the word `value` instead then no transformation from STRING to FLOAT will occur. I know that you need the expression because is a dynamic value you need to fetch from, but I just wanted to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nashornJs instead of js  like this :
<script  language="nashornJs">

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will try that.